# build android native app in Visual Studio 2015 c++

Tags: android, c++, visual-studio-2015

I am trying to build an android native app in Visual Studio 2015 c++. I opened the visual studio project using the template which is Visual C++-> Cross Platform-> Native-activity Application(Android). 
[image: Left side is the project i opened while right side is the sample i found]

I did android app before in android studio. I know that the project need layout xml as well as src but all those things come with open new project. However, the project i opened is lack of src folder and layout xml. In this case, am i need to add all these files myself? If not, how can i manipulate the GUI in app?

I actually new in native activity application. Is it i set the GUI using java and type all the c++ coding in native activity? And what is the difference between this and jni?

Answer (score 0):

> You can use the NDK to write C++ code and you can either use the JNI
>   to interface this code with a Java Android app or you can write a
>   NativeActivity which provides the interface to application lifecycle
>   events for your convenience. For my example I will use the JNI
>   approach and I will create the project using Android Studio.After
>   creating a new Blank Activity app I had to set up a few things:... http://peted.azurewebsites.net/visual-studio-2015-preview-mobile-c/